# Moving folders using gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, directory, src, libs

I have project with 3 folders (I'm using gulp), which I don't need to compile. So, I need a task, which takes 3 folders `"src/fonts"`, `"src/libs"` and `"src/docs"` as `gulp.src()` and just move them in `dest/` folder. I don't need to do something with them, just move them after building.

**My current attempt:**

```
gulp.task('others', function () {
   return gulp.src(['src/libs/**'], ['src/fonts/**'], ['src/docs/**'])
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});
```

Using this code, task move only inner files and folders(need to be wrapped), and it take only "src/libs" as `gulp.src()`

Comment: Cant remember offhand... but try this
`gulp.src(['src/libs/**', 'src/fonts/**', 'src/docs/**'])`

Comment: will check the docs now. but, at a guess... it looks like you're not passing in the incorrect source params

Comment: this works, but all inner files and folders (which live in libs, fonts, docs) are not wrapper in this 3 folders...

Comment: try specifying a wildcard for the files too. Something like `src/libs/**/*.*`

Comment: the same problem. Maybe, I need no create 3 different tasks for each folder?

Answer (score 5):

**Problem:**

> You're using [`gulp.src()`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src) wrong.

**Explanation:**

In the current state of your code, the following is happening:

- `['src/libs/**']`   gets passed to [`globs`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/concepts#globs) property
- `['src/fonts/**']` gets passed to [`options`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src#options) property
- `['src/docs/**']`    gets passed to `NOTHING`

The above explains why you're only seeing the files of `src/libs` being selected.

Thus:

```
gulp.src(['src/libs/**'], ['src/fonts/**'], ['src/docs/**'])
```

should be

```
gulp.src(['src/libs/**','src/fonts/**','src/docs/**'])
```

or (with a file wildcard `*.*`)

```
// something like this (its dirty as I'm writing this off the cuff)
// but you get the idea    

var sources = [
     'src/libs/**',
     'src/libs/**/*.*',
    ...
 ];

gulp.src(sources)
```

---

**Some More Information:**

The [docs](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/concepts#globs) specify the usage as such:

```
gulp.src(globs[, options])
```

where `globs` can only be a:

- string => `'im/a/single/directory/or/file/s'`
- (a single) array object => `['dir1','dir2','dir3','etc']`

and `options`, ... well, an [options object](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src#options) (with defined values that you can supply)

- options =>  `{ buffer: true, read: false, ... }`

---

Comment: Isn't this just copies the files instead of moving?

Comment: @sol0mka within the context of this question the OP wanted to copy assets to a `dist` location... you could make the argument that the terminology of the title is should be move/copy, but, thats not a topic for here (I believe). Please see the usage of `gulp.src()` if you're interested to find out more.